# html page not showing image in browser

Tags: html

i am using html to create a page. but the problem i am facing is i am not geeting the image. my code is as:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body style = " background:#FFA500">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>
   header_picture
    </h1>
    <img src="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Water lilies.jpg" />

    </div>
    <div>
    <h1>
    here comes the content
    </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>
    footer_picture
    </h2>
    <img src="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Blue hills.jpg" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but it is not showing me the images when i run this html file in browser..
please help me out..

```
is this possible to give image url on run time in <img src> tag in html file.. if yes how can we do that..
```

Comment: You need to add more information for a definite answer. Where is the HTML page located? What URL are you using to call it? Are you running this from a web server? What browser are you loading the page in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Water lilies.jpg` to `file:///C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Water lilies.jpg` and the same with your other URL too.

Comment: Oh I just saw you posted practically the same answer :)

Comment: nope, mine is about something else (many browsers don't allow file:// URLs from remote URLs any more). We might both be right - there isn't enough information to tell yet

Comment: @Pekka I see what you mean now. The last time I put file:/// in a live website was many many years ago when it worked, it's good that file:/// is blocked on live websites then.

Comment: The OP's file has server-side code, so they probably intend to upload this page to the Internet. If that's the case, `file:///` URLs will break. OP will have to upload the image to the server with their web page, and use the uploaded image's URL.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing local files from a non-`file://` location (even if it's `localhost`) is no longer possible in many modern browsers for security reasons.

Chrome for example will throw the following error in its console:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/path/to/filename
```

You would have to put the HTML file into a local folder (which is probably not what you want because you have server-side code in it) or move the images to a location that you can call through your web server.